# How do I close the menu of a material-ui when clicking a submenu navigates away?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a menu with submenu nested like:

```
- Example1 > 
            Example1.1
            Example1.2
- Example2 > 
            Example2.1
```

So if I click on Example, it opens a submenu with two fields Example1 and Example2.

This is the code that I use: (with [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/))

```
export const ExampleMenu = props => {
  const [dropDownOpen, setDropDownOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setDropDownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  useEffect( () => {
    setDropDownOpen(false)
  })

  return (
    <NavDropdown
      icon="th-list"
      name="Example"
      id="example-menu"
      data-cy="example"
      style={{ maxHeight: '80vh', minWidth: '300px', minHeight: '150px', overflow: 'auto' }}
    >

      <Dropdown isOpen={dropDownOpen} toggle={toggle} rigth>
        <UncontrolledDropdown nav direction="right">
          <DropdownToggle nav caret style={{ color: '#000000' }}>
            Example1
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu right style={{ marginLeft: 90, border: '0px', outline: 'none' }}>
            <DropdownItem>
              <MenuItem icon="asterisk" to="/example1_1">
                Example1.1
              </MenuItem>
            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>
              <MenuItem icon="asterisk" to="/example1_2">
                Example1.2
              </MenuItem>
            </DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </UncontrolledDropdown>
        <UncontrolledDropdown nav direction="right">
          <DropdownToggle nav caret style={{ color: '#000000' }}>
            Example2
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu right style={{ marginLeft: 90, border: '0px', outline: 'none' }}>
            <DropdownItem>
              <MenuItem icon="asterisk" to="/example2_1">
                Example2.1
              </MenuItem>
            </DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </UncontrolledDropdown>
      </Dropdown>
    </NavDropdown>
```

Now my problem is that if I click on a submenu like Example1.2, the page changes, and the submenu closes but the parent menu (the menu level with Example1 and Example2) remain open; I need to click away, out of the menu to close it.

How can I automatically close the parent menu when I click on a submenu category?

Comment: Cant you just add an onClick handler on the MenuItem and set dropDownOpen to false? <MenuItem icon="asterisk" to="/example2_1" onClick={() => {setDropDownOpen(false)}}>

Comment: We'd need to know more about your app state (tell us about [React Strap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) if need be) to know why changing route doesn't reset your app state.